# @vkontakte/create-vk-mini-app получаю ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' при подключении react к laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, vk-mini-apps

Знаю, что много кто задавал похожий вопрос, но не нашел ответа для laravel. Вообще, проблема в следующем. Создаю react проект через `@vkontakte/create-vk-mini-app`, после чего делаю сборку

> yarn build

и подключаю статику к серверу на laravel, после чего при входе в браузер, получаю ошибку в двух файлах:

> 2.1686d493.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

> main.650d9a7f.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Стандартный файл index.html после сборки:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no,user-scalable=no,viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <title>VK Mini App Boilerplate</title>
    <link href="./static/css/2.71dad8c4.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./static/css/main.15708040.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./static/js/2.1686d493.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/js/main.650d9a7f.chunk.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

сам файл лежит по пути `nameProject\resources\views\build\`. И непосредственно сам роут

```
Route::fallback(function(){
    return view('build.index');
}
```

Пробовал также собрать приложение через `create-react-app`, но там та же самая ошибка. Я так понимаю, проблема где-то на уровне сборки проекта, хотя на там же flask'е все работает.
Буду рад любой помощи, за ранее благодарен.

Comment: Проверьте ещё раз пути к файлам. Похоже вы получаете 404 вместо скриптов. Мне особенно подозрительны `./` в начале путей. Кажется скрипты должны загружаться по абсолютному пути.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Я разместил папку `static` в папке `public` и вроде как все заработало. Будет ли правильным так оставить ?